Script Run as systemd Service won't Read CSV Properly
I have a script to backup game saves from the Steam Deck to a network drive. It works perfectly when I run it on its own. However, when I configure it to run as systemd service at startup, for whatever reason it refuses to read a csv file needed to configure the script. Again, this ONLY happens when run as a service. The service WILL work if I change the current directory in the script to the directory of the csv file (also where the script is located), but then on my next reboot it causes my samba network drive mount to break for some reason. I'm so confused and frustrated, please help.
CODE SECTION IN QUESTION:
...
### Manually set script directory
#SCRIPT_DIR=/home/deck/Documents/scripts/SyncSaves
SCRIPT_DIR=~/Documents/scripts/SyncSaves
## If I force the current directory to script directory, it works, but when I reboot my mount to the network drive 'xtra' is broken (which is needed for the script).
### -> cd $SCRIPT_DIR

# Here is where we read the csv file
echo "READING GAMES DATABASE FROM SCRIPT_DIR: "
exec < $SCRIPT_DIR/sync_saves.csv
read header
while IFS="," read -r a b c d e f g h i j k l
do
# And then we process it, but none of this happens (when run as a systemd service)
...

FULL CODE:
#!/bin/bash

echo "################################################################"

#echo "It's $(date +%A)"
echo "Sytem is: $HOSTNAME"
echo "User is: $USER"
echo "Current directory is: $PWD"
echo ""

TESTING=false
if $TESTING; then
 echo WARNING - TESTING MODE ON - FILES WILL NOT BE SYNCED...
fi

#echo "param1: $1"
if [ -z "$1" ] 
then
 echo "No parameter1, defaulting to -backup"
 op='-backup'
else
 op=$1
fi
if [ $op == '-update' ]
then
 echo "Operation is Update"
else
 echo "Operation is Backup"
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]
then
 ##echo "Parameter2 is empty"
 alt=false
else
 ##echo "Parameter2 is $2"
 alt=$2
fi

#SCRIPT_DIR=/home/deck/Documents/scripts/SyncSaves
SCRIPT_DIR=~/Documents/scripts/SyncSaves

IFS='='
while read -r var val
do
 declare $var=$val
#done < common.cfg
done < <(tr -d '\r' <$SCRIPT_DIR/common.cfg)
#echo "lin_user: $lin_user"
echo "cloud_path: $cloud_path"
if $alt; then
 echo "Using alt cloud path"
 lin_cloud_drive=$alt_lin_cloud_drive
 echo "lin_cloud_drive: $lin_cloud_drive"
else
 echo "lin_cloud_drive: $lin_cloud_drive"
fi
echo ""

echo "READING GAMES DATABASE FROM SCRIPT_DIR: "
#echo "$SCRIPT_DIR"
exec < $SCRIPT_DIR/sync_saves.csv
#exec < /home/deck/Documents/scripts/SyncSaves/sync_saves.csv
#exec < <(tr -d '\r' <$SCRIPT_DIR/sync_saves.csv)
read header
while IFS="," read -r a b c d e f g h i j k l
do
 echo "game_name: $a"
 #echo "lin_drive: $d"
 #echo "win_path: $e"
 #echo "lin_path: $f"
 #echo "lin_pfx_user: $g"
 #echo "all_path: $h"
 #echo "save_folder: $i"
 #echo "game_user: $j"
 #echo "skip: $k"
 #echo "exclude_files: $l"
 #echo ""
 
 game_name=${a}
 skip=${k}
 
 exclude_files="${l//[$'\t\r\n']}"
 exclude_files="'$exclude_files'"
 
 full_path="${d}${f}${h}${i}"
 full_path="${full_path//[$'\t\r\n']}"
 full_path="${full_path}\\"
 #echo "full path: $full_path"
 
 full_path="${full_path/'{win_path}'/$e}"
 full_path="${full_path/'{lin_user}'/$USER}"
 full_path="${full_path/'{lin_pfx_user}'/$g}"
 full_path="${full_path/'{game_user}'/$j}"
 #echo "full path rep: $full_path"
 full_path=$(echo $full_path | sed -r 's|\{NA\}||g')
 full_path=$(echo $full_path | sed -r 's|\\\\|\\|g')
 full_path=$(echo $full_path | sed -r 's/\\/\//g')
 
 full_cloud_path="${lin_cloud_drive}${cloud_path}\\${a}\\"
 full_cloud_path=$(echo $full_cloud_path | sed -r 's|\\\\|\\|g')
 full_cloud_path=$(echo $full_cloud_path | sed -r 's/\\/\//g')

 #echo "full path : $full_path"
 #echo "full cloud: $full_cloud_path"
 
 backup_path1=${lin_cloud_drive}${cloud_path}\\backup1\\${a}
 backup_path1="${backup_path1//[$'\t\r\n']}"
 backup_path1="${backup_path1}\\"
 backup_path1=$(echo $backup_path1 | sed -r 's|\\\\|\\|g')
 backup_path1=$(echo $backup_path1 | sed -r 's/\\/\//g')
 backup_path2=${lin_cloud_drive}${cloud_path}\\backup2\\${a}
 backup_path2="${backup_path2//[$'\t\r\n']}"
 backup_path2="${backup_path2}\\"
 backup_path2=$(echo $backup_path2 | sed -r 's|\\\\|\\|g')
 backup_path2=$(echo $backup_path2 | sed -r 's/\\/\//g')
 backup_only=0
 #echo "backup_path1: $backup_path1"
 #echo "backup_path2: $backup_path2"
 
 if test -d $full_path; then
    if [ $skip == 1 ]; then
        echo "SKIPPING: $a - $full_path"
    elif $TESTING; then
        echo "rsync --update -av --exclude $exclude_files $backup_path1 $backup_path2"
        echo "rsync --update -av --exclude $exclude_files $full_cloud_path $backup_path1"
        echo "rsync --update -av --exclude $exclude_files $full_path $full_cloud_path"
        echo "rsync --update -av --exclude $exclude_files $full_cloud_path $full_path"
        echo TESTING MODE ON - FILES NOT SYNCED...
        if [ "$op" == "-backup" ] 
        then
            echo "OP IS BACKUP"
        elif [ "$op" == "-update" ] 
        then
            echo "OP IS update"
        else
            echo "ERROR: Unknown Operation"
        fi
    else
        if [ "$op" == "-backup" ] 
        then
            mkdir -p $full_cloud_path
            DIFFS="$(diff -qr $full_path $full_cloud_path)"
            echo "DIFFS: $DIFFS"
            #if $diffs >/dev/null; then
            if [ "$DIFFS" == "" ] 
            then
                echo "No Backups Needed: $full_path";
            else
                echo "backing up previous backups..."
                rsync --update -va --exclude $exclude_files $backup_path1 $backup_path2
                echo "backing up previous saves..."
                rsync --update -va --exclude $exclude_files $full_cloud_path $backup_path1
                echo "backing up current saves..."
                rsync --update -va --exclude $exclude_files $full_path $full_cloud_path
            fi
        elif [ "$op" == "-update" ]
        then
            if [ $backup_only == 1 ]
            then
                echo "..."
                echo "$game_name is set to backup ONLY"
                echo "..."
            else
                echo "updating current saves..."
                rsync --update -va --exclude $exclude_files $full_cloud_path $full_path
            fi
        else
            echo "ERROR: Unknown Operation"
        fi
 fi
 echo ""
 else
 echo "-$a not found, skipping: $full_path"
 echo ""
 fi

done < <(tail -n +2 sync_saves.csv)

echo "Writing to log at $SCRIPT_DIR/sync_saves.log..."
echo "Last sync - $op - by $USER on $(date) - TESTING: $TESTING" >> $SCRIPT_DIR/sync_saves.log

LOG_PATH="${lin_cloud_drive}${cloud_path}/sync_saves.log"
LOG_PATH=$(echo $LOG_PATH | sed -r 's|\\\\|\\|g')
LOG_PATH=$(echo $LOG_PATH | sed -r 's/\\/\//g')
#SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )
#$echo "Script is located in: $SCRIPT_DIR"
echo "Writing to log at $LOG_PATH"
echo "Last sync - $op - by $USER on $(date) - TESTING: $TESTING" >> $LOG_PATH

if $TESTING; then
 echo TESTING MODE ON - FILES WERE NOT SYNCED...
fi

echo SAVES SYNCHRONIZED

echo "################################################################"

exit


SERVICE (SHOULD BE FINE, BUT INCLUDING JUST IN CASE):
[Unit]
Description=SyncSaves Startup
Requires=home-deck-mnt-xtra.mount
After=home-deck-mnt-xtra.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
#ExecStart=/home/deck/Documents/scripts/svc_test/svc_test.sh
ExecStart=/home/deck/Documents/scripts/SyncSaves/update_and_sync.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

This is set up as a user service, not a system service. I'm not sure if it is possible or advisable to create a system service on SteamOS.

Try running the script with bash -x /home/deck/Documents/... and see if there are any differences between manual execution and systemd execution. Wait, is this a system service or a user one? A system service is run as root unless specified otherwise (and I don't see it specified otherwise), so ~/... = /root/....

The execution environments differ. Look at the results of  echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias in each of your environments. Also, dont use ~, it's shorthand for "my home directory", and systemd isn't you.

@muru This is set up as a user service, not a system service. I'm not sure if it is possible or advisable to create a system service on SteamOS.

"it refuses to read a csv file needed to configure the script." - How did you get to this conclusion? I suppose you have a log somewhere? Can you post the log? If not, try and log the execution to a file, then see if the script outputs some relevant message. The script is quite long, we'd better start off somewhere.

@muru I ran the script with bash -x and it works fine.

@kos I don't know how to get any diagnostic info. When I run it manually: systemctl --user start ss_lin_startup, it just outputs a portion of the script and where it should start processing the csv it just skips to the end. systemctl --user status ss_lin_startup. journalctl -u ss_lin_startup.service returns "no entries"

@muru Okay. How/where?

@waltinator Can you elaborate on what you think I'm doing wrong? Do need to encapsulate my echos in quotes or something?

@muru Thanks for the suggestion. I was hopeful that would work, but it's the same outcome.

Yes, the outcome will be the same. The point is that bash -x adds extra debug output, so you can "see if there are any differences between manual execution and systemd execution"

I found the problem. The config (sync_saves.csv) file is referenced twice. The first time here:
exec < $SCRIPT_DIR/sync_saves.csv
Then again here:
done < <(tail -n +2 sync_saves.csv)
The second time, I didn't specify the path. This script and the csv file are in the same directory, so it works fine when running the script directly. When running as a service it needs to know the path so it fails, but for whatever reason doesn't provide any error message.
